# Change VAR to array to store multiple items

Tags: javascript

so I have the a script used in a game mod, the script allowed you to hit the up arrow to quickly view other messages that you previously typed out. It stores that ONE message as chat.previous. Is there a way to turn "chat.previous" into an array, then I can just use a for loop through that array everytime the up arrow is pushed down?

Here is the snippet of the script.

```
else if (event.which == 13 && chat.input != null) {
        var value = chat.input.children("input").val();

        if (value.length > 0) {
            chat.previous = value;
            if (value[0] == "/") {
                value = value.substr(1);

                if (value.length > 0 && value.length <= 100)
                    mp.invoke("command", value);
            }
            else {
                if (value.length <= 100)
                    mp.invoke("chatMessage", value);
            }
        }
        enableChatInput(false);
        hide();
    }
    else if (event.which == 27 && chat.input != null) {
        enableChatInput(false);
        hide();
    }
    else if (event.which == 38 && chat.input != null) {
        chat.input.children("input").val(chat.previous);
    }
```

As you can see, when enter is pushed, it stores that chat message as chat.previous I would like to change it from being able to store only 1, to possibly storing 10. Then I should be able to FOR LOOP through the results. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks guys.

Comment: What does your `chat` object look like?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can do this:

```
if (!chat.previous) {
  chat.previous = [ ];
}

chat.previous.push(value);
```

Having something that *might* be an array is annoying to deal with. Make it consistently an array.

Comment: I'm sorry, Im confused where to make these changes.

Comment: Instead of where it's `chat.previous = value`.

Comment: So I could keep the bottom section as is? No need to for loop through the array?

Comment: There's probably several things that you'll need to fix, but this addresses your first question.